# Are the arms of a hurricane along wind direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, coriolis-effect

Within any tropical hurricane satellite photo we see a typical swirl pattern of clouds.

Are the arms of clouds we see aligned on the winds vector field?

Or are they on the contrary perpendiculars to the direction of the winds (as waves on the ocean surface)?

Are these arms just variations of clouds optical density?

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tropical_cyclone#Eye_and_center) has a nice image showing that while the upper layer of winds rotates clockwise (reverse of what you *normally* see - since this layer has dissipated by the edges), the bottom layer (that you *normally* see), is rotating counterclockwise.

But, the answer was about the vector field.  It looks like your intuition was correct.  In fact, it looks like those rain bands are the lulls in between as the wind whirls through the vector field - the wind goes through the open channel in between those clouds to the eye of the storm.